# TKinter destroy clicked button

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to transfer the position or the number of the clicked button to destroy it ?
By clicking on "Add Button" you can add buttons to the window. By clicking on the added buttons it should delete the clicked button, but it will delete the last added button.

Lets say i added four buttons and deleted the thrid one, the remaining buttons should be 1,2 and 4.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Programm(tk.Tk):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.add_button = tk.Button(self, text="Add Button", command=self.button_add)
        self.add_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.button_count = 1

    def button_add(self):
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Number " +str(self.button_count), command=self.destroy_button)
        self.button.grid(row=self.button_count, column=0)
        
        self.button_count += 1

    def destroy_button(self):
        self.button.destroy()
            
def main():
    root = Programm()
    root.mainloop()
    
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

class Programm(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
    
         self.add_button = tk.Button(self, text="Add Button", 
         command=self.button_add)
         self.add_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
    
         self.button_count = 1

    def button_add(self):
         button = tk.Button(self, text="Number " +str(self.button_count), 
         command=lambda : Programm.destroy_button(button))
         button.grid(row=self.button_count, column=0)
    
         self.button_count += 1

    def destroy_button(button):
         button.destroy()
        
def main():
    root = Programm()
    root.mainloop()

    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In your code, you are trying to destroy the self.button which is nothing but the last defined button.
Instead, give the button object as input to the destroy_button function so that the particular button is alone destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you create `self.button` the previous `self.button` reference is overwritten so that
clicking on any `self.button` will only ever destroy the last created button.

There are a number of ways to deal with this problem.

This solution simply commands the button to destroy itself.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Programm(tk.Tk):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.add_button = tk.Button(self, text="Add Button", command=self.button_add)
        self.add_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.button_count = 1

    def button_add(self):
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Number " +str(self.button_count))
        self.button.grid(row=self.button_count, column=0)
        # command will destroy itself
        self.button.config(command = self.button.destroy)
        
        self.button_count += 1


def main():
    root = Programm()
    root.mainloop()

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```